# Is there some way to improve the performance of passing closures in Rust?

Tags: performance, rust, closures

I have to basically go through a picture and apply different filters to it. The basic code I use for that looks like this and runs for my example in ~0.37 seconds:

```
    let mut changed = true;
    while changed {
        changed = false;
        // I need to clone here so I dont use the changed data
        let past = self.grid.clone();
        // My data is in a vector, this gives me all x/y combinations
        for (x, y) in GridIndexIter::from(0, self.width as i32, 0, self.height as i32) {
            // This gives me the index of the current piece
            let i = self.ind(x, y);
            let root = past[i];
            // Here I apply my filter (if no value, set it to a neighboring value)
            if root.elevation == None {
                let surround: Option<Tile> = GridIndexIter::from(-1, 2, -1, 2)
                    .map(|(x_add, y_add)| past[self.ind(x + x_add, y + y_add)])
                    .filter(|tile| tile.elevation != None)
                    .nth(0);
                if let Some(tile) = surround {
                    self.grid[i].elevation = tile.elevation;
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But because I want to run multiple filters, all of which are applied the same way but differ in the actual calculation (I might want to smooth the values and so on), I tried to split it into the basic logic of applying a filter and the logic of that filter, which I would set as a closure, but now it takes ~4,5 seconds for my example:

```
fn apply_filter(&mut self, condition: fn(Tile) -> bool, filter: fn(Vec<Tile>) -> Option<Tile>) {
    let mut changed = true;
    while changed {
        changed = false;
        let past = self.grid.clone();
        for (x, y) in GridIndexIter::from(0, self.width as i32, 0, self.height as i32) {
            let i = self.ind(x, y);
            let root = past[i];
            if condition(root) {
                if let Some(tile) = filter(GridIndexIter::from(-1, 2, -1, 2)
                        .map(|(x_add, y_add)| past[self.ind(x + x_add, y + y_add)])
                        .collect()) {
                    self.grid[i].elevation = tile.elevation;
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

self.apply_filter(|tile| tile.elevation == None,
        |past| {
            if let Some(tile) = past.iter().filter(|tile| tile.elevation != None).nth(0) {
                return Some(Tile {
                    elevation: tile.elevation,
                    ..past[4]
                });
            } None
        }
    );
```

Did I make a mistake? Is there some way to make closure more efficient? Is there another way to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you building/running with `--release`?

Comment: you are collecting the `GridIndexIter` into a `Vec` in the later example, but not in the other. Why not let the `filter` function take an `impl Iterator` or `GridIndexIter` directly?

Comment: Yes, Im building with release in both cases. I could take an Iterator, that would be a bit nicer, I will change that, but that shouldnt make such a drastic difference, right?

Comment: It should, because every `.collect` into a vector is an allocation of heap memory, it's not bad to allocate a few times, but you allocate for every pixel

Comment: Can you provide a minimal and **runnable** version of your code that others could use to benchmark? Without that it's really hard to provide authoritative answers to this question.

Comment: Here is a basic version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fbc7d2423dbdf790500ed21ad903ee4
But it doesnt run consistently on there, so I suggest copying it over and running it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's very hard to reproduce your code, I just wanted to suggest a version that is a bit more clear, and maybe easier to debug. Obviously this is all untested, probably doesn't compile

```
loop {
    let past = self.grid.clone();
    let updates_count = GridIndexIter::from(0, self.width as i32, 0, self.height as i32)
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(i,_)| &past[i].elevation.is_none()) // captures &past
        .filter_map(|(i,(x,y))| 
            GridIndexIter::from(-1, 2, -1, 2) // captures &self, &past
                .map(|(x_add, y_add)| &past[self.ind(x + x_add, y + y_add)])
                .filter(|tile| tile.elevation.is_some())
                .nth(0)
                .map(|tile| (i,tile))) // either Some((i,tile)) or None
        .map(|(i,tile)| self.grid[i].elevation = tile.elevation)
        .count();
    if updates_count == 0 {
        break;
    }
}
```

The version with closures could look like that (notice how `filter` is defined, it accepts iterators, not vectors)

```
fn apply_filter(&mut self, condition: fn(Tile) -> bool, filter: fn(impl Iterator<Item=Tile>) -> Option<Tile>) {
    loop {
        let past = self.grid.clone();
        let updates_count = GridIndexIter::from(0, self.width as i32, 0, self.height as i32)
            .enumerate()
            .filter(|(i,_)| condition(&past[i])) // captures &past
            .filter_map(|(i,(x,y))| 
                filter(GridIndexIter::from(-1, 2, -1, 2) // captures &self, &past
                    .map(|(x_add, y_add)| &past[self.ind(x + x_add, y + y_add)]))
                .map(|tile| (i,tile))) // either Some((i,tile)) or None
            .map(|(i,tile)| self.grid[i].elevation = tile.elevation)
            .count();
        if updates_count == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

--
**EDIT:** The following, is a simplified version of how would an iterator could be passed to a capture: [Playground of the following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bd7ac457cabf57101d58e6485f8e9ce)

```
use std::ops::Fn;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Tile(i32);

type TilesIter<'a> = &'a mut dyn Iterator<Item=Tile>;

fn apply_function<'a>(func: &'a dyn Fn(TilesIter) -> Option<Tile>) -> Option<Tile> {
    let tiles = vec![Tile(0), Tile(1), Tile(2), Tile(3)];
    func(&mut tiles.into_iter())
}


fn main() {
    let result_tile = apply_function(&|iter: TilesIter| iter.last());
    println!("{:?}", result_tile); // Some(Tile(3))
    assert_eq!(result_tile, Some(Tile(3)));
}
```

Comment: Your basic version works as expected (I had to change a few small things) and is indeed faster than mine, but I couldnt figure out how to pass the iter into the closure sucessfully. Can you tell me how that works? The declaration doesnt work in any combination I tried and I couldnt find any examples of taking an Iterator, only of giving one out of a closure.

Comment: @kroetnaton I edited the answer, it might help. It really turned out to be cumbersome

Comment: Thank you so much, now it finally works at the same speed as the basic version, when passing the iter instead of the list.